# Angular Material button is not rendering

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have followed steps to install material design, but when I add button I don't get the MD style.

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

**Package.json file**

```
{
  "name": "apimap",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "github:angular/cdk-builds",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "github:angular/material2-builds",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

I have also added css theme + material design in index.html
Added MD modules in app.mudule.ts but I get a basic html button style, only the mat-menu-item are in MD style.

**Update:** A screen capture of the button:
[image: button not rendering]

when I click on it

[image: menu item rendering]

Comment: You need to add material theme

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just for confirmation, have you added MatButtonModule in appModule imports? Can't add it as comment because of my reputation :P

Comment: Yes I have added it

Comment: I have added MatMenuModule but not MatButtonModule . Now is working. Thanks